# Avro schema backward compatibility error in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I try to add a new field to my avro schema and I expect a retrocompatibility for the old messages as specified in the avro specification: [Source](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Schema+Resolution).

I updated my Avro schema with a new field `v2_0.avsc`.
I try to consume an old message, written with the old schema `v1_0.avsc`, it throws the error `java.io.EOFException: null`.
I added a default value for the new field but without success.

Old schema `v1_0.avsc`:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Test",
  "fields": [
     {"type": "string",  "name": "field_1"}
    ,{"type": "string",  "name": "field_2"}
    ]
}
```

The new one `v2_0.avsc`:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Test",
  "fields": [
     {"type": "string",  "name": "field_1"}
    ,{"type": "string",  "name": "field_2"}
    ,{"type": "string",  "name": "field_3", "default": "default_value"}
    ]
}
```

I tried also, several combinaisons of union type, for the new schema and the default value:

With default strings and different union order

```json
    ,{"type": ["string", "null"], "name": "field_3", "default": "default_value"}
```

```json
    ,{"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "field_3", "default": "null"}
```

Or just `null`

```json
    ,{"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "field_3", "default": null}
```

But all of them produce the same error:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:542)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:173)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:493)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:282)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:188)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:142)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)
```

My consumer use the new schema `v2_0.avsc`:

```java
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
....

        
        // Create consumer configs
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        // Kerberos
        ...
        
        // Create consumer and subscribe to the topic
        KafkaConsumer<String,  byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
        

        ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
            

        byte[] data = record.value();
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(SCHEMA);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(data, null);
        GenericRecord message;
                    

        message = reader.read(null, decoder);
```

My producer use the old schema `v1_0.avsc` to try backward compatibility:

```java
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
....


        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, CLIENT_ID);
        // Kerberos
        ...
        
        try ( KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties) ) {
            

            GenericRecord payload = new GenericData.Record(SCHEMA);
            payload.put("field_1", "001");
            payload.put("field_2", "002");
            DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(SCHEMA);
            byte[] serializedBytes;
            try ( ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ) {
                BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
                writer.write(payload, encoder);
                encoder.flush();
                serializedBytes = out.toByteArray();
            }
            
            ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> message = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, serializedBytes);
            producer.send(message);
```

I tried with libs `org.apache.avro:avro` 1.8.1 and 1.11.0 with the same bad result.

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you not using a schema registry? Without that, you'll not know if data is truly backwards compatible

Comment: Also, I don't think you need `SpecificDatumWriter` if you are going to be using `GenericRecord`, anyway

Comment: Adding an optional field should be fine, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "field_3", "default": null}  Am curious of the extra double quotes in the example pasted. More at : https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#full-compatibility

Comment: @OneCricketeer: I don't want to use Schema Registry, I want to use only apache libs not Confluent.

Comment: @OneCricketeer: is there any other way than with a `SpecificDatumWriter` ? In this test I used a `GenericRecord` but I also tried with a bean generated from avro-maven-plugin, with the same error.

Comment: I didn't say Confluent. I said a registry. This one is Apache licensed https://www.apicur.io/registry/ or https://karapace.io/. In any case, `GenericDatumWriter` is a superclass of specific one. The specific one should only be used for the generated SpecificRecord subclasses

Comment: Also, I suggest you remove Kafka dependency while you test. You can do the exact same thing here with local byte arrays in one Junit method

Comment: @OneCricketeer: I just tried with a `GenericDatumWriter` instead of the `SpecificDatumWriter` but I have exactly the same error :(
About the schema registry, thanks for links but I want to do that without any if possible. Maybe it's that, can I have a schema backward compatibility without schema registry ?

Comment: You can, but it will be centrally checked by the server, and prevent runtime errors like those that you are getting... More specifically, each test that you are running, are you clearing the topic? Or are you producing new events over and over? Or do you keep running the consumer, and only changing the schema there? In other words - it's difficult to know where your error is happening because you have multiple schemas shown here, and we don't know what is `SCHEMA` in your producer.

Comment: The Producer produce the old one the `v1_0.avsc`.  
The consumer read with the new one `v2_0.avsc`.